# Using Gibbon on Heroku for MailChimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gibbon

I am using Gibbon to automatically send a new user's email to Mailchimp.
In my Heroku logs I get this error message:

```
  Gibbon::MailChimpError (Signup disabled for "a@a.com"):
```

My gibbon.rb has my Mailchimp API key:

```
Gibbon::API.api_key = "My API key is in here ..."
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = true
```

My controller calls this action:

```
  def subscribe

      @list_id = "123456789"    # My Mailchimp list ID
      gb = Gibbon::API.new

      gb.lists.subscribe({
        :id => @list_id,
    #    :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]}
        :email => {:email => "a@a.com"}        
        })
      redirect_to home_membership_path
  end
```

Also, in my development environment I get this error message which may or may not be a clue:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in HomeController#subscribe

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: How did you fix this error? I am going through the same right now...